# How to contrain the aspect ratio of a div

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I have a **parent** div with a variable size, and a **child** div inside with its `width` set to 100% to fill up the **parent** div horizontally.

I'd like the `height` of the **child** div to be equal to its `width` at any time, to have an aspect ratio of 1:1 for the **child** div. The **parent** div has a different aspect ratio.

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: How would you change the height and width of the child div? through javascript or ?

Comment: I know I could do it with JS but I'd like to know if there were any CSS way to achieve this. I'm working with React so I'd like to avoid manipulating the DOM directly.